# pl/sql remove element from array

Tags: arrays, plsql, oracle11g

I need to remove element from array. I have tried to use array.delete(n) function, but it deletes all elements from identifier n. How to just delete exact element n ?

For example if array is 1 2 3 4 5, and n = 3, after delete it should look like following 1 2 4 5.

My code so far :

```
DECLARE
  /* declare type array */ 
  TYPE number_index_by_number IS TABLE OF number INDEX BY binary_integer;

  v_n NUMBER := &sv_n;
  v_m NUMBER := &sv_m;
  v_min Number; 
  v_tmp Number;
  v_array number_index_by_number; 
  v_sorted_array number_index_by_number;
begin
  for i in 1..v_n 
  loop
    v_array(i) := dbms_random.value(1,1000);
  end loop;
  for j in v_array.first..v_array.last
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_array('||j||') :'||v_array(j));
  end loop;
  <<i_loop>> for i in 1..v_m
  loop
    /*set first array value to variable min*/
    v_min := v_array(1);
    v_tmp := 1;
    <<j_loop>> for j in v_array.first..v_array.last
    loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_array('||j||') :'||v_array(j));
      if (v_min > v_array(j)) THEN
        begin
          v_min := v_array(j);
          v_tmp := j;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(j);
        end;
      end if;
    end loop;
    /*problem is in at this line*/
    v_array.delete(v_tmp);
    v_sorted_array(i) := v_min; 
  end loop;
  for i in v_sorted_array.first..v_sorted_array.last
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_sorted_array('||i||') :'||v_sorted_array(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: what symptoms do you have of v_array being deleted all at once?

Comment: it doesn `t delete all at once. It works like for example. If declared array is 1 2 3 4 5, and n = 2, after array.delete(n) array contains only two elements. 1 and 2

Comment: but it kind of makes sense regarding to your algorithm. The question is when is it happening? I mean, just open an anonymous block and try it, you'll see it works fine. I think your algorithm is the problem. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collection_method.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce any of the behaviour you describe.  I could not get the `delete` collection method to do anything other than what it is documented to do.

However, there are a few errors in your code that could do with being tidied up.

Firstly, I should point out if you delete an element with key `3` from a PL/SQL associative array, there is then nothing with key `3` in the array.  The remaining values don't 'shuffle' down to fill the gap.  If there was an element with key `4` before the delete, the same element will still have key `4` afterwards.  As a result, if you delete element `j` from a PL/SQL associative array `v_array` and then attempt to get `v_array(j)`, you will get a 'no data found' error.  You should check to see whether the element exists, using `v_array.exists(j)`, before attempting to get a nonexistent element.

Secondly, the element with index 1 may get deleted before the last iteration of the outer loop.  If this happens, `v_array(1)` will fail with a 'no data found' error.  It would be better to assign `NULL` to `v_min` and `v_tmp` at the start of the loop, and assign to them during the loop if `v_min` is `NULL` or greater than `v_array(j)`.

Finally, it seems your code returns the `v_m` smallest numbers from `v_n`.  It would be worth verifying that `v_m` is less than or equal to `v_n`, as otherwise this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Luke ;) Yeah, I agree with you, that v_m and v_n values must be checked as you say, but this code is only for testing purpose, because I `m learning pl/sql. But thanks for your good advice, now I understand there was my problem ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm affraid you cannot use a built-in method like this.
Instead of you shoud create a temp array to collect the elements prior to and afterwards the selected one from the original array, and return the temp array.